# Sending text messages without formatting using Text belt or cellnumber@provider.net

Tags: python, api, networking

Textbelt is an API for sending text messages free. Works great, but the text arrives in this format:

FRM:root
SUBJ:txt
MSG:whatever your message is

Is there a way to send just the text message using script below without FRM, SUBJ, or MSG labels?

```
import requests

message = raw_input('Enter a Message: ')
number = raw_input('Enter the phone number: ')

    payload = {'number': number, 'message': message}
    r = requests.post("http://textbelt.com/text", data=payload)
    if r.json()['success']:
        print('Success!')
    else:
        print('Error!')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm the creator of [Textbelt](http://textbelt.com/) and unfortunately FRM and SUBJ are built in.  Some cell providers reject messages that don't have those fields set, and right now there is no way to customize them.

Because Textbelt is [open source](https://github.com/typpo/textbelt), one alternative is to host your own Textbelt server and set the From and Subject fields yourself in `lib/text.js`.